# Required mods to make RFI compatibel with Uniswap V3

Tags: uniswap

An RFI contract:

1. deducts a transfer fee
2. "reflects" fees to users (redistribution) efficiently. This has the effect of increasing user balances passively and (potentially) unexpectedly.

AFAIK, these tokens are not compatible with Uniswap V3 because the invariant x * y = k isn't maintained when the received tokens are less than the expected tokens, owing to the fee deducted.

In order to make such a contract compatible with Uniswap V3, changes are needed but I'm uncertain if this is the complete list or if each of these is even a concern:

1. on ERC20.transfer() to V3 Pool, do not deduct a transfer fee.
2. on ERC20.transfer() from a V3 Pool,  do not deduct a transfer fee (necessary?)
3. exclude V3 Pools from balance accumulation (messes up *their* accounting?)

Which of those are necessary, which can be safely dismissed and what is overlooked here?

Thanks!

Comment: As this question is very advanced, I suggest hitting Uniswap dev (Discord?) directly.

Comment: Agreed. Possibly someone here knows.

Comment: Did you get the answer to this? I was looking for it too, afaik it will break some things but not sure if you found a better implementation